# limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-integration, trigonometric-integrals, sequence-of-function

Consider the following sequence of functions and their integrals on $[0,1]$. Evaluate the limit of the following integral if possible

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx$$

At first glance, I do not know if the limit exists or not. Wolfram alpha will not take the limit for me, but it did evaluate the integral. The result is terms of a function I do not understand, but from looking at the series expansion:

$$x^k \left(\frac{kx}{k+1} - \frac{kx^2}{k+2} + \frac{kx^3}{k+3} - \dots\right)$$
it appears as though the limit is $0$ since $x \in [0,1]$. However, I have attempted the problem two different ways, and I am getting that the result is infinity. I am curious where I maybe going wrong.

Note: I am not looking for an answer. I just want to see where my logic is wrong (mainly in my 2nd attempt) so that I can try to make the correction.

Attempt 1: I can pull the $k$ outside the integral and get

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} k \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k}{1 + x} dx$$.

Now, $|\frac{x^k}{1+x}| \leq \frac{1}{1+x} = g(x)$ since we are on $[0,1]$. Since $g(x)$ is integrable, and dominates $f(x)$, the dominated convergence theorem tells me I can pass the limit inside.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx = \infty $$ due to the factor of $k$.

Now, outside of the fact that I have not done measure theory for quite some time, I am uncertain about this for two reasons. One, DCT refers to Lebesgue integrable functions. I am always hesitant when I use it during a discussion of Riemann integration. Secondly, while I am definitely allowed to pull the $k$ outside of the integral, I am not sure I am allowed to apply DCT on the result without $k$, and then put the $k$ back inside along with the limit. If I had to dominate $\frac{kx^k}{1 + x}$, I am not sure it would work. These uncertainties made me want to try to brute force this with Riemann integration.

Attempt 2:

I will rewrite the integral as

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} k \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^k}{(\sqrt{1 + x})^2}dx$$ so that I can apply Trigonometric substitution. I would get

$\sec(\theta) = \sqrt{1 + x}$

$\tan(\theta) = \sqrt{x}$

$\tan^2(\theta) = x$

$2\tan(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)d\theta = dx$

Substituting,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} k \int \frac{\tan^{2k}(\theta)}{\sec^2(\theta)} 2 \tan(\theta) \sec^2(\theta) d\theta$$

Cleaning this up,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k+1}(\theta) d\theta$$

Now, I can pull out 2 of the tangents.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k - 1}(\theta) \tan^2(\theta)d\theta$$

Using the identity $\tan^2(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta) - 1$,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) \sec^2(\theta) d\theta - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

The first integral can be done with $u$-substitution. Let $u = \tan(\theta)$. Then, $du = \sec^2(\theta) d\theta$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{u^{2k}}{2k}\right] - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

Now, I can back substitute.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{\tan^{2k}(\theta)}{2k}\right] - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

Again,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{x^k}{2k}\right]_{0}^{1} - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

Evaluating,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \frac{1}{2k} - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta) d\theta$$

At this point, I can say the first limit is $1$. Now, I still have an odd power of tangent in the second integral. So, I can repeat this process again

$$1 - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k - 3}(\theta) \sec^2(\theta) d\theta + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k - 3}(\theta) d\theta$$

Then,

$$1 - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{u^{2k-2}}{2k-2}\right] + \lim_{k \to \infty} \int \tan^{2k - 3}(\theta)$$

Again,

$$1 - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{\tan^{2k-2}(\theta)}{2k-2}\right] + \lim_{k \to \infty} \int \tan^{2k - 3}(\theta)$$

Then,

$$1 - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[\frac{x^{k-1}}{2k-2}\right]_{0}^{1} + \lim_{k \to \infty} \int \tan^{2k - 3}(\theta)$$

Evaluating,

$$1 - \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \frac{1}{2k-2} + \lim_{k \to \infty} \int \tan^{2k-3}(\theta) d\theta$$

Then, this limit is also $1$

$$1 - 1 + \lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan^{2k-3}(\theta) d\theta)$$

So,

$$\int \tan^{2k-3}(\theta) d\theta)$$

Well, this is very nice. I have ended up with a single integral with an odd power of tangent. So, I can repeat these two steps over and over until I am left with.

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \int \tan(\theta) d\theta$$

after going through all of the powers. Well, this integral I know

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[- \ln|\cos(\theta)| \right]$$

Going back to our trig sub, we can see that

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}}$$. Therefore,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \left[ -\ln|\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}|\right]_{0}^{1}$$

Evaluating,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} -2k\ln|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}| = \infty$$

This matched the result I got before, and I will much better about this because I just used straight up integration rather than a sophisticated tool that I don't know very well, the dominated convergence theorem.

My uncertainty lies in that the answer does not appear to be $\infty$ based on the power series wolfram alpha gave. Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: First deal with $\int_0^1 x^kf(x) \,dx$ and show that if $M$ is a bound for $f(x) $ on $[0,1]$ then the integral doesn't exceed $M\int_0^1 x^k\,dx$ and hence tends to $0$. Next use integration by parts for your integral.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{kx^k}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x}\,\color{#C00}{kx^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{1a}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{u^{1/k}}{1+u^{1/k}}\,\color{#C00}{\mathrm{d}u}\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_0^1\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{u^{1/k}}{1+u^{1/k}}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1c}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac12\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac12\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $kx^k=x\cdot kx^{k-1}$
$\text{(1b):}$ substitute $u=x^k$ so that $\mathrm{d}u=kx^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(1c):}$ Monotone Convergence or Dominated Convergence (dominated by $\frac12$)
$\text{(1d):}$ evaluate the limit
$\text{(1e):}$ evaluate the integral

Comment: Note that $kx^{k-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is often denoted as $\mathrm{d}x^k=\mathrm{d}\!\left(x^k\right)$

Comment: Do you have a source where that is used? I have literally never seen that before, and I would like to read some more about it for when I teach Calculus in case another student sees this.

Comment: It is most often used with [Riemann-Stieltjes Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), though it is also used in [Integration by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), among other places.

Answer (score 2):

1st attempt: You can't apply the dominated convergence theorem to the set of functions $\frac{x^k}{1+x}$ and then bring in the $k$ after you've evaluated the limit. For dominated convergence, you need a sequence of integrable functions that are bounded by an integrable function and converge pointwise to an integrable function.

So, dominated convergence does say
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{x^k}{1+x}dx = 0$$
because $\frac{x^k}{1+x}$ converges pointwise to the function $f(x) = 0$ on $(0,1)$, and indeed these functions are bounded by $\frac{1}{1+x}.$ Once you bring in the $k$ here, you have to try to apply dominated convergence to the functions
$$\frac{kx^k}{1+x},$$
which is an entirely different problem because when you look at $x = 1$, we see that these functions diverge to $+\infty.$ In general, you can't separate out limits unless you know that each of them converge.

Also, your measurability concerns are trivial: these functions are continuous, and if a function is Riemann integrable on a compact set, they are lebesgue integrable on said compact set. (The issue arises when you integrate over the real numbers.)

2nd attempt: you need to be more careful with how you apply limits. You can't just take a limit of one part of an equation and take the limit of another part of the equation years later. The terms you were throwing away make up a nontrivial part of the limit.

So, let's take your method of eventually getting to $\int \tan(\theta) d\theta.$ Let's fix $k$, apply your reductions, and see what we get.

\begin{align} 
 \int 2k \tan^{2k+1}(\theta)d\theta &= 2k \frac{x^k}{2k(1+x)} \bigg|_{x=0}^1 - 2k \int \tan^{2k-1}(\theta)d\theta
\\
&=
2k \frac{x^k}{2k(1+x)} - 2k\frac{x^{k-1}}{(2k-2)(1+x)} + 2k\int \tan^{2k-3}(\theta)d\theta...
\\
&=
2k \bigg( \frac{x^k}{2k(1+x)} - \frac{x^{k-1}}{(2k-2)(1+x)} + ... \pm \frac{x^1}{2(1+x)} \bigg)\bigg|_{x=0}^1 \pm 2k\int \tan(\theta)d\theta.
\end{align}
You see that we can't just take the limit as $k \to \infty$ because of the tail terms (i.e., $\frac{x}{1+x}$,) so you have to find some other way of obtaining this limit.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a different way to do the limit?

Comment: The other answers give good methods, so I'd just default to those. Personally I'd do what robjohn did. You could also try integrating by parts, $f_k' = kx^k, g_k = 1+x$ and see that you get 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k}{k+1}x^{k+1} \frac{1}{1+x} \bigg|_{x=0}^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{k}{k+1}x^{k+1}\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}$$ 
and look at each of those limits.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\lim_{k \to \infty} {kx^k}=0$ for $x\in(0,1)$, which allows the integration below
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx
=
\lim_{k \to \infty,\epsilon\to 1} \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx
 =\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{2} dx=\frac12
$$

Comment: I'm not follow the step where you involved the epsilon. Why is it going to 1? And how did it remove the 1 + x in the denominator?

Comment: I'm not following that. What does that mean and what does it have to do with epsilon going to 1?

Comment: @NolanP - because $\lim_{k \to \infty} {kx^k}=0$, except when $x$ is close to 1. So, the integration is only non-vanishing near $x=1$. You only need to integrate $\int_{\epsilon\to 1}^1 (\cdots )dx$

Comment: Ok I see that now. Wow, that's the second answer on this problem that has used notation I've never seen before. I wonder if this problem is above my level of comprehension. Two of the answers I don't understand. Now what about the next step? Where did the 1 + x go?

Comment: @NolanP - since you only integrate $\int_{\epsilon\to 1}^1 (\cdots )dx$, you replace $1+x$ with $1+1=2$.

Comment: How so? How does writing the integral like that mean $1 + x$ is replaced by $1 + 1$?

Comment: @NolanP - because the integration is over the range $\int_{\epsilon \to 1}^1$. So $x$ can be replaced by 1.

Comment: I'm lost. I don't see how the limits imply that. I'm sorry, this notation is new to me. I genuinely thought this problem was just a "real hard Calc II problem," not a problem that involved any sort of tricks with epsilons. This is going above my head.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, $|\frac{x^k}{1+x}| \leq \frac{1}{1+x} = g(x)$ since we are on $[0,1]$.

You miss the factor $k$, if you want to use dominated convergence theorem, you have to show $|\frac{kx^k}{1+x}| \leq g(x)$ on $[0,1]$, where $g(x)$ is independent of $k$.

> $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx$$

$$I_k=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{kx^k}{1+x} dx=\frac{k}{k+1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x} dx^{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{k}{k+1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k+1}}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}I_k=\frac{1}2+\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^{k+1}}{(1+x)^2} dx$$

Since $$\frac{x^{k+1}}{(1+x)^2} \le\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}~~~\text{for}~~x\in[0,1]$$
and $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$. So by dominated convergence theorem, we can interchange the limit and integration. Namely,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}I_k=\frac{1}2+\int_0^1\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{(1+x)^2} dx=\frac{1}2$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you did when you wrote $dx^{k+1}$. I have never seen that before.

Comment: That's integration by part. @NolanP

Comment: I don't understand that. I have never seen that notation before. Can you explain what it is? Maybe if you explain it I can try to decipher what it is?

Comment: For example, $\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x\Leftrightarrow xdx=\frac{1}2dx^2$, did you see this notation before? @NolanP

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not seen that either. I have never seen a power on the differential $dx$ in this context. I have only seen that with higher order derivatives.

Comment: No, it is not a power on the differential, $dx^2$ means $d(x^2)$. Btw, you know how to do integration by part, right?

Comment: Sorry I have been away for some time and wasn't checking this. I do know integration by parts, but I still don't recognize that notation.

Comment: Can you show me an example for the  integration by part have your learned?

Comment: $\int x e^x dx$. $u = x, du = dx$. $dv = e^x dx, v = e^x$. Then, $uv - \int v du$. This becomes $xe^x - \int e^x dx = xe^x - e^x$

Comment: Ok, so you have $v=e^x~~~~ (1)$ and $dv=e^x dx~~~~ (2)$, if you replace $v$ in $(2)$ with $(1)$, you get $de^x=e^xdx$, right? This notation saves a lot of time, and you don't need to write $u$ or $v$ every time.

Comment: I suppose so, but I find that quite bizarre. Do you know of a source that uses that notation? I've seen sources write a $D$ next to a function to represent a derivative occasionally, but I can say I have never seen it with a lowercase $d$. It almost makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: if you wrote $dv$, it is actually $d~v(x)$, because $v$ is a function of $x$, if you are comfortable with $dv=d~v(x)$, then why not comfortable with plugging in the exact expression for $v(x)$, i.e. $v(x)=e^x$?

Comment: Because I really don't like the fact that there is a $d$ right in front of a function. That would be a nightmare for the intro Calculus students in the class I teach. Some of them would be naive and think it's a differential. I now see what you're doing, but I will respectfully say that I don't like it. I am interested to see it in a source so that I can make the students I teach aware of it in case they come across it. That way they don't get confused as I did.

Comment: But the fact is when you wrote $dv$, $d$ is in fact in front of a function $v=v(x)=e^x$

Comment: That's not how I view it when I write $dv$. I view it as a differential. $dv$ is an entire quantity (a small quantity). I don't like to think of them separately, and I can confidently say neither would my Calculus students. Look, right now we're getting into an argument about notation. There's no reason for us to have this. My opinion is that I don't like that notation, and I am not going to use it. If you want to remove it from your answer, I am happy to give it more thought, but as of right now, I want to move on.

Comment: what do you mean "more thought"? The notation shouldn't affect your thought.

Comment: It affects my thought because I'm not comfortable with it. I have to try to process notation along with a problem I'm struggling with. That's not why I posted this. I posted this to see what I was doing wrong, not to learn new notation.

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect, because if you like $dv$ then you just interpret it as $dv$, it never affects and shouldn't affect your understanding on the math. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral

Comment: I have never learned Riemann-Stieljes integration. Sorry. Is it used in other context?

Comment: you can see the integration by part which is mentioned in that link

Comment: So in terms of Riemann-Stieljes integration, that is how they do integration by parts. So this answer would not be acceptable on my exam because we did not cover Riemann-Stieljes. Sorry, I definitely can no longer consider this answer unless it is changed. I would be marked wrong for it because we didn't cover it. I wish we had a way to read minds to determine that early on before we got into this long debate of confusion.

Comment: If you told your students, $dv$ and $v=e^x$, then why is it forbidden to plug in $v$ with $e^x$ to become $de^x$? Another example is how do you explain $(x^2)'=2x$? Do you use the notation $\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}=2x$? If you use this derivative notation, then you have $d(x^2)=2xdx$. I think essentially what you refuse to accept is not the notation for integration by part, but the notation for derivatives.

Comment: I do not use that notation. I use $y = x^2$ and then write $dy/dx$. Now that I am aware of this, if a student were to use it, I would not mark them wrong because I don't teach like that. However, I certainly would not teach it one because I am not comfortable with it myself, but also because if it made me confused, it could certainly confuse them. Look, this is the last message I am sending in this conversation. I'm trying to study for an exam myself, I don't want to argue about notation. I don't like this notation, and until I learn Riemann-Stieljes I will choose to avoid this personally.